# Перенаправление вывода xcopy

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Добрый день.

Вызываю консольное приложение через CreateProcess, далее через pipe читаю вывод в консоль.
Со всеми консольными функциями работает, кроме xcopy. Xcopy ничего не выводит и не отрабатывает, хотя если запустить ее руками из консоли Windows, то все работает.
Вопрос: как можно прочитать консольный вывод xcopy, запущенной через CreateProcess.
Delphi 7.

Answer (score 1):

не факт, что xcopy вообще что-либо выводит в консоль. можно убедиться, перенаправив результат в файл: `xcopy c:\ d:\ > test.txt`, если файл будет пустой - то и вы ничего не заберете из консоли.